# Условие в htaccess: "кроме главной"

Tags: .htaccess

Есть условие в htaccess - отдаем код 410 всем страницам кроме тех кто оканчивается на ".html". Но вот главная тоже с 410 ошибкой теперь, как главную страницу добавить в это условие?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^ - [G]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
# обратились к файлу, который имеет расширение отличное от .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
# и обратились не к корню сайта
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
# и обратились не к файлу index (с любым расширением) в корне сайта
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\. [NC]
# тогда 410 ошибка в ответ
RewriteRule ^ - [G]
```

Comment: почему то не работает условие `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$` Главная страница - 410

Comment: @ДмитрийПортнов, старый редирект в кеше браузера точно не закеширован?

Comment: Да проверил, все точно. Оставил только вот это `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^ - [G]` Все равно 410 на главной. Может дело  в цмс - modx?

Comment: @ДмитрийПортнов, у вас в .htaccess еще какие-то правила прописаны? Если да, то в обновите вопрос, допишите ниже текущего текста, что у вас там сейчас имеется.